# plot() and imshow() relationship

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to understand if there is a way to compare how `plot()` and `imshow()` works for the case where I am not using imshow() to display an image.

Via the `plot()` function, I am specifying the points that I want to plot and also optionally the color that i want the points to be in. For example, `plot([1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], 'ro')` will create a plot with those points colored "red". Via the `imshow()` function, we specify the color (or intensity) of each point and a figure is created with the points colored accordingly. Sure, `imshow()` allows me to color each point differently.

Is there a way to relate them?

Comment: Are you asking how to color points by a third variable through a colormap?  (e.g. `scatter`: http://matplotlib.org/examples/shapes_and_collections/scatter_demo.html)

Answer (score 0):

Functionally there is no relationship since plot() is for plotting functions and imshow() is for visualizing 2D arrays or 3D arrays(with color image dimensions) as image. But you can produce similar visualizations from both for your case,

```
a = [1,2,3];
b = [1,2,3];
Image = ones(3,3,3);
for i=1:numel(a)
    for j=1:numel(b)
        if i==j
           Image(a(i),b(j),:)=[1 0 0];
        end
    end
end
imshow(fliplr(Image));
```

You can interpolate the above over a larger 3D grid for better resolution. This kind of manipulation of imshow() to mimic plot() can only give you the outline or general shape of the mathematical function, but not the x and y axis properties like ticks and labels.